# How to use `std::multimap` or any other container to sort multiple values?

Tags: c++, algorithm, sorting, data-structures, stdmap

I am looking forward to solving a problem where first I need to sort some data.

Example -  **Key** -> **Values** in `std::multimap`.

It stores data in increasing order automatically on the basis of keys.

But problem arises, when I need to sort repeated *keys* according to their *values*.

I have tried a silly way to just simply transfer a set of repeated *key*s into a new `std::multimap` and sort and store back but that's is too much of repeated codings to implement a single thing causing increase space and time complexity.

For Example:

```
Key - Values
 9  -  e
 3  -  b
 1  -  c
 1  -  a
 5  -  d
 9  -  a
```

Sorted value expected as:

```
1 - a
1 - c
3 - b
5 - d
9 - a
9 - e
```

But the output using multimap will return:

```
1 - c
1 - a
3 - b
5 - d
9 - e
9 - a
```

And this problem further escalates when there are multiple sets of *value*s corresponding a *key*.

As I am new to `C++`, I am unable to figure out how to do so using pre-existing containers.

This thing easy to implement in `SQL` but in `C++`, I don't know.

Comment: In C++ you are not supposed to use containers for sorting. You are supposed to use [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).

Comment: Please provide your attempt of how you tried to solve it. Otherwise you hardly will find anyone trying to help you.

Comment: show the code which should be fixed.

Comment: "*This thing easy to implement in SQL but in C++, I don't know.*" Well, yeah. One of these is a relational database, the other is a general programming language. `multimap` isn't a database. And SQL database tables aren't sorted either; you simply get a *view* of them that is sorted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you slightly can change the data structure,

1. you could use either *[std::vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) of `std::pair<int, char>`* and then
   sort it accordingly,
2. or simply use a [`std::set<std::pair<int, char>>`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set), which will be sorted as per the default [`opererator<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/pair/operator_cmp) of `std::pair`.

Comment: Thanks, this would solve my problem upto an extent but I won't be able to perform any modification on values in set.

Comment: @Mrityunjay I would suggest asking a new question regarding that, with showing **the code** and **explaining** what *"I won't be able to perform any modification on values in set"*. In that way, others can help you in a better way.